# Show $\log(|z + \sqrt{z^2 + 1}|)$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a textbook saying $\log(|z + \sqrt{z^2 - 1}|)$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$ but I fail to see why.

I know $\log(|f(z)|)$ is harmonic if $f$ is analytic, but in our case $f$ contains a square root and so no matter how you choose the branch cut you will always end up with a function which is not analytic on all of $\mathbb{C} \setminus [-1,1]$. On the other hand, checking the Laplace equation explicitly requires way too much computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on the conventions of the book.
In this case, if we denote by $\sqrt{}$ the [principal square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Principal_square_root_of_a_complex_number)
$$
\sqrt{z} := \sqrt{|z|} \, e^{i \arg(z)/2}
 \qquad \text{where} \qquad
\arg(z) \in (-\pi,\pi],
$$
then we can define a function $f$ by $f(z) = z+ s(z) \, \sqrt{z^2-1}$ where
$$
s(z) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if } \mathfrak{R}(z) > 0 \text{ or } \mathfrak{R}(z) = 0 \land \mathfrak{I}(z) \geq 0, \\
-1 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

It easy to show that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\backslash [-1,1]$, so $\log(|f|)$ is harmonic.

Comment: To all who struggled like me with understanding why this $f$ is holomorphic: the trick is to note that while $\sqrt{z}$ always has a branch cut, this cut gets mapped to two cuts under the transform $z = w^2$. So we get to choose two branches, not just one like in $\sqrt{z}$, and by choosing them cleverly we can make $\sqrt{w^2}$ holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. This is precisely what flipping the sign in $f$ does.